# Ubuntu Limit sudo user to password reset only

Tags: 14.04, server, sudo

I would like to limit one of my sudo users to only be able to reset a users password. I do not want them to have any other administrative privileges but that.

I know how to block certain access, but how would I block everything but `passwd`.

Comment: Hmm... and what would stop them from resetting the password for `root` (or for any unrestricted sudoer) and thereby gaining unlimited privileges?

Comment: @Olorin That would be a decisive NO! Kayenine is asking about giving a non-administrative user permissions to execute a very specific administrative all-powerful command that virtually allows for unlimited access to the system.

Comment: @BarBar1234 "all-powerful command that virtually allows for unlimited access to the system" has been addressed already by steeldriver. The facts of the question still make it a duplicate, irrespective of what the command does.

Comment: @Kayenine please take a look at the extra line I added to the script file that removes all control characters before they get passed to the chpasswd command.

Comment: Read `man sudoers` several times. What you ask is possible, one can even restrict them to the naked `passwd` command, and disallow `passwd root`. However, since `/usr/bin/passwd` is `SetUID root` it seems redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you are even considering restricting admin privileges of any user you should first do `sudo gpasswd -d [username] sudo` as soon as possible because they have full access to the system until removed from sudo.

Now, there is a way to allow this type of task, but it still is very dangerous and problematic and can lead to disasterous situations.

1. Obviously you cannot allow this user to have unrestricted access to `passwd` because then there will be nothing stopping him from `passwd root` .
2. However, you still want to give him access to reset passwords of users not belonging to administrative group. This is a strategy I can think of:

You have a power user named `fakeboss` that will be resetting passwords for users. You make him a special folder, lets call it `/usr/local/fakeboss/` that only his group and sudo can access.

A root creates a basic user named `user1`, and a script that will have read and execute permission only called `user1pw.sh` with:

`chmod 755 user1pw.sh` and puts it in `/usr/local/fakeboss/`

inside the script root writes, ($1 is the new password argument passed, and I checked it quickly but most piping of other commands either resulted in permission denied or changed user1 password to the piped string, but still I would need to double check this part)

```
#!/bin/bash
filtered=echo $1 | tr -d '[:cntrl:]'
echo "user1:$filtered" | chpasswd
echo "You just reset password for user1"
```

then in `/etc/sudoers` root adds

`fakeboss  ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/local/fakeboss/user1pw.sh`

as well as `/usr/local/fakeboss/` to the secure_path line in /etc/sudoers

you top it off with an alias for `fakeboss` 

`alias user1pw ='sudo /usr/local/fakeboss/user1pw.sh'`

and they now can change `user1` password to a new one they send as argument with lets say:

`user1pw IamYourBoss!`

which will set user1 password to IamYourBoss!

and this tactic can be implemented for all users chosen by root, and these users will be able to have their passwords unlocked by `fakeboss`. More importantly, `fakeboss` has no access to the password reset scripts as they are unwriteable and has no `passwd` permissions nor any `sudo` permissions beyond these password reset scripts. One last thing I would add is certainly some serious logging mechanism as well perhaps system message sent to `root` stating that `user1` had their password reset at this and this time for security and integrity.

I wrote this quickly and might have missed a detail or two but this is certainly way safer than allowing a pseudo-sudo user unrestricted access to `passwd`.

Edit: Added input filtering,